# How to match a value on a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

0Dear all I have this code below: (I do know it's incorrect, by the way):

```
list1 = ([33, 37], [38, 45], [46, 54], [55, 62], [63, 74], [75, 79], [80, 90], [91, 95], [96, 110], [111, 112], [113, 125], [126, 147], [148, 159], [160, 185])
list2 = [100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 250, 275, 300, 325, 350, 400, 450, 500]

   new_dict = {k: v for k, v in zip(list2, list1)}
   print(new_dict)
   weight = input("enter weight :")
   for key, value in new_dict.items():
    value = int(new_dict[value])
    if weight <= [value] or weight >= [value]:
        dose = k
        print(dose)
```

Basically what I am trying to come up with is a program that dose bands a med for you. I'll explain, the drug in question is infliximab and I am using a dose of 3mg/kg, so if I was to have a patient that was 36kg, i'd get a dose of 108mg, which I'd like my program to go through the values in the dictionary (list1) find out that 36 is between 33 and 37 and return a dose of 100mg (key) instead.
I am quite new to python and I do know there is a simple way but I currently lack the wherewithal and would appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: 1. `weight` is a string while you expect it to be an `int`. 2. Why `[value]`? what do you expect to happen when (supposedly) comparing an `int` and a `list`?

Comment: Ok, thanks, so I need to convert weight to a string

Comment: 3. `value` is a value from `new_dict`. Doing `new_dict[value]` makes no sense at all

Comment: I understand, what I am trying to do is replicate the VLOOKUP function from excel (partial match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but rather than zip the lists together making them a little harder to work with for this problem, let's find the proper range and it's index and use that index to find the dose.

```
list1 = ([33, 37], [38, 45], [46, 54], [55, 62], [63, 74], [75, 79], [80, 90], [91, 95], [96, 110], [111, 112], [113, 125], [126, 147], [148, 159], [160, 185])
list2 = [100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 250, 275, 300, 325, 350, 400, 450, 500]

weight = float(input("enter weight :"))
dose = "n/a"

for index, bracket in enumerate(list1):
  if bracket[0] <= weight <= bracket[1]:
    dose = list2[index]
    break

print(dose)
```

Alternatively, if you are keen on using `zip()` then you might:

```
list1 = ([33, 37], [38, 45], [46, 54], [55, 62], [63, 74], [75, 79], [80, 90], [91, 95], [96, 110], [111, 112], [113, 125], [126, 147], [148, 159], [160, 185])
list2 = [100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 250, 275, 300, 325, 350, 400, 450, 500]

weight = float(input("enter weight :"))
dose = [amt for bracket, amt in zip(list1, list2) if bracket[0] <= weight <= bracket[1]]
if dose:
  print(dose[0])
```